# Toabsolute() retrieves correct path on development machine but not deployement server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, absolute-path

`ToAbsolute()` method retrieves the path correctly on the development machine but not on deployment. When I use `ToAbolute(~/Login.aspx)` returns path to specified location correctly. the same on the uploaded website returns just `/login.aspx`. what else am I missing here?

Comment: I am really stuck here please help

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is your IIS settings for application path. Ensure that they both are set up with the same folder structure and you should be good from there.

In IIS, an Application can be added under a Site at a particular URL... In your local system it appears you've added your application under the /applicationname directory. On the remote server, it appears to be configured for root. Compare the two IIS instances side-by-side and note the differences.

Comment: No I don't need physical path. I need virtual path.`Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server`

Comment: What value does the `ToAbsolute` call return locally for ~/Login.aspx?

Comment: /applicationname/login.aspx

Comment: Sorry ... can you be a bit more elaborate on your statements.

Comment: what is your suggested code sample then.. in your scenario.. The website has been configured under the domain name domain.com/wwwroot

Comment: It's not code, it's IIS. Do some googling about how to work with IIS if you're unfamiliar - I can offer solutions but teaching you the basics of a technology is a different matter.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis  I am already reading this part of the same link you posted..